# mod_rewrite для nginx

Tags: nginx, winginx

Установлен локальный сервер Winginx, пытаюсь настроить аналог mod_rewrite в файле nginx.conf чтобы работали ссылки на разделы сайта на Wordpress вида `http://mysite/about/`, но разные варианты того, что надо прописать в конфиге, не работают.
Вот так выглядят разделы server в конфиге nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen   127.0.0.1:80;

    root home/localhost/public_html;
    index index.php index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    location ~ /\. {deny all;}

    location / {

        if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
            root home/$2/public_html;
            access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
        }

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
            root home/$2/public_html;
            access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
        }

        if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include fastcgi_params;

    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:443;
    include ssl.conf;

    root home/localhost/public_html;
    index index.php index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    location ~ /\. {deny all;}

    location / {

        if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
            root home/$2/public_html;
            access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
        }

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
            root home/$2/public_html;
            access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
        }

        if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

Подскажите, что нужно прописать чтобы заработали ссылки?

Answer (score 2):

вообще [рекомендуемый для *wordpress*-а](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress) `location /` должен выглядеть так:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

но у вас в `location /` внесены какие-то свои настройки, смысл которых мне оценить сложно. попробуйте вставить директиву `try_files` сначала *до* своих настроек, а если не поможет, то *после* (а возможно, и *вместо*).

Comment: да уже пробовала эту настройку добавить, и до, и после, и вместо, главная страница работает, а остальные -- нет.

Comment: было бы хорошо, если бы вы в вопросе привели пример того, что требуется для *mod_rewrite*, без «аналогов».

Comment: не совсем поняла вопрос?

Comment: вы пишете: *пытаюсь настроить аналог mod_rewrite в файле nginx.conf чтобы работали ссылки на разделы сайта*. видимо, вам известно, что должно быть в конфигурации `apache+php` и файле `.htaccess`, чтобы работало то, что вам требуется. приведите эту информацию, тогда станет понятнее, что должно быть в конфигурации `nginx+fastcgi`.